# How to login an aspx page with JSoup?

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm trying to login into a site using JSoup but I'm having trouble getting that.
I know after login site redirect me to another page.but i want to use one url

I'm not sure if the URL or login data is incorrect.

The login page is here

I'm currently trying with the following code:

```
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        try {

            String urlLogin = "http://www.ime.org.ir/members/entrancecheck.aspx";
            String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36";
            Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(urlLogin)
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();

            Document loginPage = response.parse();

            response = Jsoup.connect(urlLogin)
                    .data("_LASTFOCUS", "")
                    .data("_EVENTTARGET", "")
                    .data("_EVENTARGUMENT","")
                    .data("__VIEWSTATE", loginPage.getElementById("__VIEWSTATE").val())
                    .data("__PREVIOUSPAGE", loginPage.getElementById("__PREVIOUSPAGE").val())
                    .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", loginPage.getElementById("__EVENTVALIDATION").val())
                    .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$entrancecheck1$username", "21465")
                    .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$entrancecheck1$pass", "amir1365")
                    .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$entrancecheck1$Button1", "ورود به پايگاه")
                    .userAgent(userAgent)
                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .cookies(response.cookies())
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .execute();

            Document doc = response.parse();

            Elements description = doc
                    .select("table[id=table2]");
            // Locate the content attribute
            desc = description.html();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Set description into TextView

        web= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

        web.loadData(desc, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);

        web.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(15);
        web.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid to follow the redirect and check if the response header contains `Location` header.

```
response = Jsoup.connect(urlLogin)
                .data("__LASTFOCUS", "")
                .data("__EVENTTARGET", "")
                .data("__EVENTARGUMENT","")
                .data("__VIEWSTATE", loginPage.getElementById("__VIEWSTATE").val())
                .data("__PREVIOUSPAGE", loginPage.getElementById("__PREVIOUSPAGE").val())
                .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", loginPage.getElementById("__EVENTVALIDATION").val())
                .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$entrancecheck1$username", "21465")
                .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$entrancecheck1$pass", "amir1365")
                .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$entrancecheck1$Button1", "ورود به پايگاه")
                .userAgent(userAgent)
                .followRedirects(false)
                .cookies(response.cookies())
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .timeout(0)
                .execute();

if(response.hasHeader("Location")){
    System.out.println("Login ok!");
} else{
    System.out.println("Login not ok!");
}
```

Complete code:

```
package com.github.davidepastore.stackoverflow34220319;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

/**
 * Stackoverflow 34220319 question.
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        String urlLogin = "http://www.ime.org.ir/members/entrancecheck.aspx";
        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36";
        System.out.println("First request...");
        Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(urlLogin)
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .userAgent(userAgent)
                .timeout(0)
                .execute();

        Document loginPage = response.parse();
        System.out.println("Second request...");
        response = Jsoup.connect(urlLogin)
                .data("__LASTFOCUS", "")
                .data("__EVENTTARGET", "")
                .data("__EVENTARGUMENT","")
                .data("__VIEWSTATE", loginPage.getElementById("__VIEWSTATE").val())
                .data("__PREVIOUSPAGE", loginPage.getElementById("__PREVIOUSPAGE").val())
                .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", loginPage.getElementById("__EVENTVALIDATION").val())
                .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$entrancecheck1$username", "21465")
                .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$entrancecheck1$pass", "amir1365")
                .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$entrancecheck1$Button1", "ورود به پايگاه")
                .userAgent(userAgent)
                .followRedirects(false)
                .cookies(response.cookies())
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .timeout(0)
                .execute();

        if(response.hasHeader("Location")){
            System.out.println("Login ok!");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Login not ok!");
        }
        Document doc = response.parse();

        Elements description = doc
                .select("table[id=table2]");
        // Locate the content attribute
        String desc = description.html();
    }
}
```

Thanks to [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34224584/1992780) for pointing out the wrong form names.